# DialogFragment behaves differently when invoked via ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

I'm experiencing strange, perhaps version-specific behavior with my DialogFragment subclass when testing the following steps:

(1) Open the dialog
(2) Leave the app with either the Home key or the Recent Apps key
(3) Return to the app, and the dialog is no longer visible. It *seems* to be briefly, translucently visible behind the main activity.
(4) Rotate the device, and the dialog re-appears.

This bug occurs on my Asus TF700T pad running Android 4.2.1, and it does *not* occur on my Motorola Razr phone running Android 4.1.2 (which has a menu key rather than an overflow button).  Moreover, it *only* occurs if the dialog is opened via the overflow menu - dialogs opened via ActionBar items do not exhibit this issue! And finally, the issue does not occur if you do an orientation change *before* pausing the activity.

I have found a [very similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016043/dialogfragment-displayed-from-oncontextitemselected-doesnt-survive-onpause-onre) which includes depressing comments like "This is clearly an Android bug." There are associated [bug reports.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41901) Please, say it ain't so...

My workaround for this issue is in onResume(): I check the FragmentManager for existing dialogs with findFragmentByTag; if any are not null I dismiss and re-show them. But I'd like to understand what's really going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to this question is the Google bug report linked above. I changed my design to avoid the problem, so I have not tried the workaround someone there has posted.